# RunProcess and SystemShell - some built in commands don't work?

Tags: linux, process-control

I'm running a zsh shell:

```
$SystemShell = "/bin/zsh"
```

My problem is that some basic system-level commands don't work in `RunProcess`. For example, echo works but exec, source, and many other build it shell commands don't:

[image]

It gives an error:

```
RunProcess::pnfd: Program source not found.  Check Environment["PATH"]. >>
```

The docs say that by default, the subprocess will inherit its process directory and environment variables from the Wolfram Engine, so I tried setting the ProcessEnvironment with an association to match my environment vars in the terminal. But that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here, shouldn't all system level shell commands be accessible?

Answer (score 7):

I am able to use both, `RunProcess` and `StartProcess`, to execute a built-in shell command. At least it works for me ***on OSX***, with zsh or sh shell.

Here is a minimal example with the built-in command `source` (like in the OP's question).

First, let's choose our shell :

```
myshell = "/bin/zsh"; (* or "/bin/sh" *)
```

This is some trivial shell script we'd like to `source`:

```
code = "#! " <> myshell <> "\nhi () {echo \"Hello World\";}"
```

> ```
> "#! /bin/zsh
> hi () {echo \"Hello World\";}"
> ```

that we can export directly to an external file (inside for example home directory):

```
Export["~/file2source", code, "String"];
```

These are different ways to `source` the script in the file:

**1.**

```
RunProcess[myshell, "StandardOutput", "source ~/file2source ; hi "]
```

> `Hello World`

**2.1**

```
process = StartProcess[myshell];
WriteLine[process, "source ~/file2source  ; hi"];
ReadLine[process]
WriteLine[process, "exit"];
```

> `Hello World`

**2.2**

```
process = StartProcess[myshell];
WriteLine[process, "source ~/file2source ; hi ; exit"];
ReadString[process]
```

> `Hello World`

***Comment:*** It seems there is a problem with the approach consisting in reading the buffer (like `ReadString[process, EndOfBuffer]`) when the command is contained in a notebook cell with other commands ... I'll explain that in a different post.

Answer (score 6):

`RunProcess` can only run commands that are separate binaries, and commands like `source` and `exec` are built into the shell, not independent of it. You could execute them by sending them to a running `zsh` process through a process object returned by `StartProcess[$SystemShell]`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I run a process within a process. I'm trying to launch an ipython shell inside a virtualenv within the zsh shell.

Comment: @M.R. Does that work : `RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "source yourfilepath"]`

Comment: @SquareOne No, it gives me this: during evaluation of `In[126]:= OpenRead::noopen: Cannot open ZSH-ENV... ZSH-RC.... >>
Out[127]= $Failed`

Comment: @SquareOne Try it with StartProcess and then try to run another command using WriteLine, it doesn't work...

Comment: @M.R. No, actually I got it work with StartProcess but not with RunProcess ... ??